# Case statement for a Business Objects variable

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

My team are in the process of recreating BO reports (infoview) in SSRS via oracle stored procedures and some of these reports have custom variables at report level (equivalent of expressions in SSRS)

Now I'm not the greatest at case statements but I need to replicate this variable in my select statement and I can't seem to get it right.

```
=Sum(If(Match([REP Con Name];"PROPERTY MAINTENANCE*");[REP Practical Cost Amount];[REP Practical Cost Amount]*1.2))
```

What would the case statement equivalent of the above be?

Answer (score 0):

```
=Sum([REP Practical Cost Amount] * CASE WHEN [REP Con Name] = "PROPERTY MAINTENANCE*" THEN 1.0 ELSE 1.2 END)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Works like a charm. Much appreciated.